# Is there a way to extract the first line from stderr and store it to a variable in the shell script executing the function?

Tags: bash, pipe, stderr

Say I have a command I'm running in my script whose first line in `stderr` is something I need.  I'm using `stderr` because `stdout` is already being used for transferring some other data. I still need the rest of `stderr` for user feedback, so I still want to display everything after the first line.

```bash
cmd() {
  ssh usr@remote.machine.com '
    printf "stderr data line 1 (important)\n" 1>&2
    printf "stdout data line 1\n"
    printf "stderr data line 2\n" 1>&2
    printf "stdout data line 2\n"
    printf "stdout data line 3\n"
    printf "stderr data line 3\n" 1>&2'
}

# What sort of shell magic would I need to extract
# only the 1st line of stderr?
cmd > store_stdout_to_this_file ??? read -a first_line_of_stderr
echo "$first_line_of_stderr"
```

I can't use a pipe, as pipes only pipe stdout, and even if I were to rearrange them, then the other end of the pipe is in a different process space.

Comment: Could you have the function send that line to another file descriptor, or is it a command you don't control? You're not limited to just stdout and stderr...

Comment: I could, but let's say that cmd isn't actually running locally, but remotely across `ssh`.  In which case, I don't think `ssh` would forward those descriptors.

Comment: Actually, I don't think `ssh` forwards stdout and stderr separately. Or would you be redirecting stdout on the remote system?

Comment: Just tested it, and `stderr` and `stdout` are forwarded separately.  I can redirect `cmd`'s `stdout` to `/dev/null`, all I get is the `stderr` stuff.

Comment: Although, if a password is requested, that is requested on `stderr`, so I'd also have to figure out a way to still output that to the screen to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several methods to do this, all with different limitations and oddities. Probably the simplest is to redirect stderr to a background subshell (via process substitution) that runs `read` once, then `cat`:

```
cmd >outputfile 2> >(read firstline; echo "First line is: '$firstline'"; cat -u)
```

But that puts the first-line processing in a subshell, so any variables it sets will be lost when that shell exits. I suppose you could have it write the line to another file, and then read that from the main script afterward...

Another possibility is to put the command you're trying to capture in the process substitution, and `read` and `cat` in the main shell:

```
{ read firstline; cat -u; } < <(cmd 2>&1 >outputfile)
echo "First line is: '$firstline'"
```

Note that the output redirection from `cmd` must be done inside the process-substituted part (since its stdout is being sent to the `read`-`cat` part), and the `2>&1` must be first so stderr doesn't go to the same place.

Comment: Yes, that 2nd method looks like what I need to do.  What's with the `-u` switch.  I've never seen it before.  It shows up as ignored in the man pages I've looked it up in.

Comment: The `-u` means unbuffer the output, so `cat` will forward error/status messages immediately rather than waiting until some buffer fills up. If your `cat` doesn't support it, that might mean it doesn't buffer anyway, or you might have to use `unbuffer cat` or something similar. You may just have to test to see what works.

Comment: Wow! Surprised that worked without interfering with `ssh`'s password prompt.  Wonder how that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```bash
line=
while read -r; do
   [[ -z $line ]] && line="$REPLY" || echo "$REPLY"
done < <(cmd 2>&1 >out.log)

stderr data line 2
stderr data line 3

# check $line
echo "$line"

stderr data line 1 (important)
```

i.e. redirect stderr to stdout first and then redirect stdout to `out.log` and finally pipe output using `head -n 1`.

Comment: I actually need the original `stdout` as it contains other important data.

Comment: And what happened to the rest of `stderr` which I said is needed for user feedback?

Comment: Yes, and leave the rest for user feedback.  _"I still need the rest of `stderr` for user feedback, so I still want to display everything after the first line."_